# std::priority_queue to accept 2 parameters (for Djikistra's Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, declaration, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, priority-queue

I was working with Djikistra's Algorithm , its first time i am implementing it .
But i dont know how to declare priority_queue with two parameters .
 For 1 parameter (min-priority_queue) i could easily do :

```
priority_queue<int,std::vectors<int>,std::greater> >
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? What do you want these parameters to be? Maybe it's just me, but I don't have the slightest idea what you're asking for.

Comment: @us2012 : like we have 1 parameter priority queue , say A , then we can push 1 integer in it like A.push(5); , i want to be able to handle 2 values like A.push(5,3); and sorting based on 1st nos. (here 5) .

Comment: Ah! Well, either use an `std::map` (which is also sorted), or put pairs (`std::pair<int,int>`) into the `priority_queue` and write a comparator that compares the `pairs` based on their first element.

Comment: @us2012: no need to write, std comparator behaves exactly like you need

Comment: the std::priority_queue won't work for Dijkstra, since it cannot handle updates of the weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::pair, where first is the distance and second is vertex number.

```cpp
typedef std::pair<int, int> pii;
std::priority_queue<pii, std::vector<pii>, std::greater<pii> > dijkstra_queue;
```

Comment: dijkstra_queue.push(), top() and pop() is all you need for dijkstra. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/ for details

Comment: And how to retrieve elements too ?<br>
djkistra_queue.top().?

Comment: But , situation has changed , hasnt it ? I want to get value of djikstra_queue then i will have 2 choices , 1st part of pair & 2nd part of pair ? How do i deal it ?

Comment: yes, top() to retrieve. top().first is the distance, top().second is the vertex.